# Позиционирование блоков с помощью CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css3, html5, css-grid

У меня есть 8 блоков обернутых в `grid-контейнере`.

Два нижних блока находятся слева. Как мне поместить их по середине использую только `CSS Grid Layout`?

```css
.block__products-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-element {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F7F0DD;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .9s;
}

.grid-element-one:hover {
  background-color: #ffec41;
}

.grid-element-two:hover {
  background-color: #FF2929;
}

.grid-element-three:hover {
  background-color: #4f75f4;
}

.grid-element-four:hover {
  background-color: #49cc63;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__products-grid">
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-one"></div>
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-two"></div>
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-three"></div>
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-four"></div>
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-one"></div>
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-two"></div>
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-three"></div>
  <div class="grid-element grid-element-four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Грид для того и нужен, что он сетка. Используй flex вместо него.

Comment: Корректно ли будет задавать при адаптации страницы в классы "grid-element" и тому подобное flexbox'ы?

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что можно положить два блока в грид из трех клеток, чтобы они не пересекались и были ближе к центру. Возможно вам стоит попробовать сделать более сложный грид с 6 колонками в ширину, где 1-6 объекты будут занимать по 2 клетки рядом друг с другом, а последние 2 объекта займут центральные 4 колонки по 2 каждый.

например, как тут:

```
grid-template-areas: 
 "a a b b c c"
 "d d e e f f"
 "g g g h h h"
```

Где для g и f вы зададите отступы или выравнивание

Альтернативно можно поместить большой объект в нижний ряд грида и использовать flex для одномерного выравнивания.

Comment: Принципиально хочу сделать это Гридами. Проверил ваш метод, он не сработал в моем случае https://codepen.io/VadimStrelov/pen/xoQvoM